# Downgrade my current NVidia driver to a specific version

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, nvidia-graphics-card, aptitude, downgrade

Recently my NVidia driver was updated from `270.41.06-0ubuntu1` to `270.41.06-0ubuntu1.1`, but I have troubles with it. Is there an easy way to rollback with `aptitude` to the version before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create `/etc/apt/preferences` with content

```
Package: nvidia-current
Pin: version 270.41.06-0ubuntu1
Pin-Priority: 1001
```

and then run `sudo aptitude install nvidia-current`.

You should also be able to do just

```
sudo aptitude install nvidia-current=270.41.06-0ubuntu1
```

but then it will ask you to upgrade this on every future `dist-upgrade`.

Comment: Oh yeah thank you very much Daniel, that was it. I can't tell you how happy you made me :)! (By the way it was `nvidia-current`)

Comment: @DanLee: Good with the package name feedback. I'll update the post accordingly. `nvidia-glx` is the name on Debian Sid, which will probably propagate to Ubuntu sooner or later. The Ubuntu machines I had access to showed `nvidia-current` as well, but they are 10.04 and 10.10 respectively, so I thought maybe it had changed.